# I need to replace a string in html sed is not working

Tags: awk, sed, aix, html

Here is the code in the shell script I have used

```
sed 's/xyxx/$date1/' /u001/Scripts/abc.html > /u001/Scripts/abc.html
```

The code is trying to print HTML tags inside AWK command

```
nawk 'BEGIN{
      FS=","
      print "<HTML>""<HEAD>""<p>Hi All,<br><br>There are no cases closed on the"
      print  "xyxx that meet the criteria for submission</p>"
      }
      END{
      print "<p>Regards,<br>Support Team</p></BODY></HTML>"
      }
      '
```

Comment: You should state your desired result and the actual result.

Comment: do u want to replace `xyxx` with the value of `date1` or just as `$date1`?

Comment: I need to replace xyxx with value of date1 inside the file or can I use print command itself inside awk

Comment: use `sed -i` to edit files in place. Your command will not work, because redirections are done first. So you'll be ending up with an empty file.

Comment: Also, if you need variable replacement, you need to put the sed command in double quotes for bash to expand the variables.

Answer (score 1):

In this command,

```
sed 's/xyxx/$date1/' /u001/Scripts/abc.html > /u001/Scripts/abc.html
```

the redirection happens first! So the shell opens `/u001/Scripts/abc.html` for writing and empties it. Then the `sed` command runs, but the input file is empty, so no output either.

As the comments suggest, you should use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/xyxx/'"$date1"'/' /u001/Scripts/abc.html
```

which will

- create a backup file with extension `.bak` and overwrite the original file (`-i.bak`)
- and use the variable value of `$date1`, because it's put in double quotes, unlike the rest of the `sed` expression.

Comment: I am unable to get the output on the mentioned command above sed -i.bak 's/xyxx/'"$date1"'/' /u001/Scripts/abc.html

Comment: make sure that `$date1` does not contain characters that are interpreted by `sed`, e.g. a slash or an `@` will cause problems.